# limit of a product of independent random variables

Tags: probability

I'm stuck with the following problem:

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be independent random variables which uniformly distributed on intervals $[-a_1,a_1],[-a_2,a_2],...$ respectively. Define $Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. Then $Y_n$ tends to zero almost surely if $\limsup_
{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n \leq 2$. And the limit of $Y_n$ doesn't exist if $\lim_
{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n/n^2)=c>0.$

I tried to look at it using martingale, since $E(Y_n|F_{n-1})=0$ for all n, and the martingale convergence theorem suggests the limit exists almost surely when $\limsup_
{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n \leq 2$, but I don't know how to prove the limit is exactly zero. I've not thought of a proper tool for the second part either. Could anybody give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a law of large numbers for martingale differences that says if $E[Y_n|F_{n-1}]=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{E[Y_n^2]}{n^2} < \infty$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = 0$ with prob 1.  If you already know $Y_i$ converges to something, then its average converges to the same thing, which is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have good "almost sure convergence" results for **sums** of iid random variables.  Therefore you might consider $Z_n = \log \left(|Y_n|/\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log |X_i/a_i|$.  Note that $\log |X_i/a_i|$ are iid with mean $-1$ and
standard deviation $1$.

Comment: This arrangement is really neat! But I'm sorry I still don't know how to achieve the goal that limit of $Y_n$ is zero, since $\prod a_i$ would be infinity as n goes to infinity, even when $a_i$ is bounded. This seems to be in our way?

Comment: By the Strong Law of Large Numbers, $Z_n/n \to -1$ almost surely.  If $a_n < r < s < e$ for sufficiently large $n$, $(\log \prod a_n)/n < \log s < 1$, and so $(\log |Y_n|)/n < \ldots$

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much for your kind reply!